# Adding to an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner to java, and need some help.

I am trying to convert an Abstract Data type Foo which is an associated list to an Arraylist of the strings B. How do you loop through the list and add each string to the array.

I may be over thinking it, but I am lost now.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: please show us the parts of your code where you are having difficulties

Comment: @Steven: Completely agree. Its hard to know what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Refer https://programmerzdojo.com/java-tutorials/java-arraylist/

Answer (score 49):

Instantiate a new ArrayList:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Iterate over your data structure (with a for loop, for instance, more details on your code would help.) and for each element (yourElement):

```
myList.add(yourElement);
```

Comment: I think in the latest versions of Java, you don't need to specify the type a second time: `List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();`

Answer (score 13):

If you have an arraylist of String called 'foo', you can easily append (add) it to another ArrayList, 'list', using the following method:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.addAll(foo);
```

that way you don't even need to loop through anything.

Comment: what case are you talking about? please be more specific.

Comment: say int[] foo={1,2,3} The code wont compile because addAll wont take such parameters. JDK 1.7.

Comment: are you trying to add the `int` array `foo` to another `int` array? Or do you want `int[]` to `ArrayList[Integer]`?

Comment: `int[] foo = { 1, 2, 3 };
  
int[] foo2 = new int[foo.length];
  

for(int i = 0 ; i < foo.length ; i++)

foo2[i] = foo[i];`

Comment: add to ArrayList. You can read the document of ArrayList. addAll() does not take array at input.

Comment: just convert your `int[]` to an `ArrayList` and do `addAll()`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do something like:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for( String s : foo )
{
    list.add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array list can be implemented by the following code:

```
Arraylist<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(value1);
list.add(value2);
list.add(value3);
list.add(value4);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to iterate through your abstract type Foo and that depends on the methods available on that object. You don't have to loop through the ArrayList because this object grows automatically in Java. (Don't confuse it with an array in other programming languages)

Recommended reading.
[Lists in the Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help, I've solved my problem :)    Here is the code if anyone else needs it :D

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld {


public static void main(String[] Args) {

Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(9);
list.add(11);
map.put(1,list);        

    int First = list.get(1);
    int Second = list.get(2);

    if (First < Second) {

        System.out.println("One or more of your items have been restocked. The current stock is: " + First);

        Random rn = new Random();
int answer = rn.nextInt(99) + 1;

System.out.println("You are buying " + answer + " New stock");

First = First + answer;
list.set(1, First);
System.out.println("There are now " + First + " in stock");
}     
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 9, there's an easy way with less number of lines without needing to initialize or `add` method.

```
List<String> list = List.of("first", "second", "third");
```