# Entering commands into a arraylist

Tags: java, input, arraylist

So I have this assignment, and it says to create a arraylist using standard input, and constantly prompt the user for commands. Now, I understand how to add commands, WITHIN the code, but I dont understand how to take what the user puts in, and turn that into a command in the arraylist. Here's what I got so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment216{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner n = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a command:");
      String command = s.nextLine();
      System.out.println("If you entered 'add', then enter a name:");
      String input = n.nextLine();
   }
}
```

*EDIT* New Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment216{
   public static void main (String args[]){
      ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
      Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter command, or type 'quit' to exit");
      String quit = e.next();
      boolean exit = quit;
      if(exit = true){
         System.exit();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand what do you want to achieve...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding to an ArrayList Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935613/adding-to-an-arraylist-java)

Comment: http://bigcatsoftware.net/occ/ap.htm read the first one

Comment: Done editing my response. I didn't check it but it should work (worst case, it might have a syntax error) but apart from that it should give you an idea on how to proceed. Not that I implemented conditions for add and remove only. Program terminates on quit being entered. You might want to add more commands as you are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request that the user types in his commands and then check using the method from the String class equalsIgnoreCase() and compare it and see if it is the same as add, remove, etc. (whatever commands you need). Use if-else statements to implement the logic. For example if user input resolves to add, then you add an element. If user input is not any of the common functions, then print message that there was an error and so on. I cannot type out the answer in code as this is an assignment.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment216{
  public static void main (String args[]){
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner e = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter command, or type 'quit' to exit \n");
    while (!e.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {  // As long as input not equal to quit
      if (e.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("add") {
        System.out.println("Enter name to add:\n");
        String name = e.nextLine();
        names.add(name);
      }
      if (e.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("remove") {
        System.out.println("Enter name to remove:\n");
        String name = e.nextLine();
        names.remove(name);
      }
    }
    if(e.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
      scanner.close();
      System.exit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand what your trying to say, but I dont know how to put it into code. I got rid of the Strings from my code, and replaced it with a boolean and a If statement, but I'm lost.

Comment: Could you post your updated code? I can look at it and then update my answer with a close enough algorithm

Comment: As you can see, im having trouble with the data types.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the add() method in the [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) interface. Might help.