# Add card to hand in blackjack

Tags: java, arrays, blackjack

How do I add a card to my hand when it says "addCardToHand" I tried `card++;` and `hand++;` neither worked. Is there a problem with my code, or did I just left something out? I feel like I need to add something but, I don't know what.

```
private AbstractCard[] hand;
private int winCount; 

public AbstractPlayer() {
    hand = new AbstractCard[0];
}

public AbstractPlayer(int score) {

}

public void addCardToHand( AbstractCard card ) {
   AbstractCard[] NewHand = new AbstractCard[hand.length+1];
    for ( int i = 0; i < NewHand.length; i++) {
        NewHand[i] = hand[i];   
    }
}

public void resetHand() {
    hand = new AbstractCard[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably because `hand[]` has nothing in it. It gets created as an array with size 0, (no elements), and then when you add a card, you pull from the `hand[]` at index 0, but since the `hand[]` has no elements, it's not pulling from anywhere.

Basically, nowhere in your code does `hand[]` ever get to be an array with any elements in it, so when you take from `hand[0]` there's nothing there, because in `hand = new AbstractCard[0];`, `[0]` is the size of the array.

EDIT:
You might want to look into using an ArrayList ([Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)) ([Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935613/adding-to-an-arraylist-java)), because they don't have a pre-defined size. In your case, you're adding elements as you go, so an ArrayList be very helpful. With an ArrayList, you won't have to constantly create new arrays.

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to keep track of the next insert position for cards with some state like `private int insertCursor = 0;`

Your `addCardToHand(AbstractCard)` method can then simply be

```
public void addCardToHand(AbstractCard card) {
    hand[insertCursor++] = card;
}
```