# Populate an ArrayList with for loop

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to populate an `ArrayList` using a loop. What am I doing wrong? When I print the `ArrayList` nothing gets printed. I think my problem is related to `numbers.size()`.

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(7);
for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Comment: See this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935613/adding-to-an-arraylist-java

Comment: Hi, I didn't include print method above, but here is my print method:
     public static void print( ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
        for (int n: nums){
            System.out.println(n);
            
        }

Answer (score 2):

In line `ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(7);` 7 - isn't size. Size still equal 0, because you didn't add any elements. So numbers.size() is 0.

Argument in constructor is `initialCapacity`. This is a start length of internal array in ArrayList.

Comment: Ah I see, how could I add values using a loop. Is that possible?

Comment: @Carl Just replace `i <= numbers.size()` to `i <= 7`

Comment: @VladimirParfenov Not a good idea to hardcode it

Comment: Just define a int variable `int SIZE` to your desired length and then do `for int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++`

Comment: I understand now guys, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Initially, the list is empty, meaning `numbers.size()` returns `0`. Therefore the loop will never be entered because `1 <= 0` is `false`.

Comment: Ah I see, how could I add values using a loop. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `numbers.size()`. This line `ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(7);` create an ArrayList with initial capacity enough equal or higher than 7 but the size of the created ArrayList is 0. So the program doesn't go instead your loop

Comment: I understand now, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(7);
```

You need to specify the type for both sides of the assignment

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.size(); i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
```

Indexes for arrays and ArrayLists start at 0, so make i zero, and use a less-than instead of less-than-or-equal-to. Finally, this should work. Just edited this, seems like I was slightly wrong. Make numbers.size() a constant instead, and that should work

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(7);
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Comment: "*You need to specify the type for both sides of the assignment*" if you are talking about *generic type* then it since Java 7 we can use diamond operator `<>` instead of rewriting generic type again.

Comment: I understand now, thanks for your help