# How can I remove the null by using just arrays and loop (no other methods)?

Tags: java, arrays

I have this code here and the output comes with `null`. How can I remove it?

The input is:

> hello hello i i am norman

```
      for (int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
        boolean isUnique = true;
        int freq = 0;
        for (int j=0; j<words.length; j++){
            if (i==j){
                freq++;
                 continue;
            }
            if (words[j].equals(words[i])){
                 isUnique = false;
                freq++;
            }
        }

        if (isUnique){

            uniquewords[i] = words[i];}

        frequency[i] = freq;

       }

    }
```

Output :

> null null null null am norman

Comment: What is `uniquewords`, how is it defined? If an ArrayList, simply use `uniquewords.add()` instead of `uniquewords[i] =`. Does this answer your question? [Adding to an ArrayList Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7935613/adding-to-an-arraylist-java)

Comment: i can't use Arraylist just array and loops

Comment: This is most definitely a homework question, I have seen something very similar for one of my apprentices. Please note that we are not here to do you homework for you.

Comment: I have made some minor formatting changes to (try to) make your question look nicer - I can across it in the "Help and Improvement" review queue. I hope you approve.

Comment: You have 4 answers, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (uniquewords[i] != null){
   System.out.println(uniquewords[i]);
}
```

add this check while printing

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have same index i corresponding to same word in words, uniquewords, and frequency. You can't have that if you don't want nulls in uniquewords: if the word is not unique, it would stay null.

If you just care about what you print, do what Rajendra is suggesting.

If you want an array with the unique words, and you can't use e.g. ArrayList, you need to create that result array at the end when you know which the unique words are. Then you'd know what length you need. You would need to pass the frequency array twice:

```java
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] == 1) count++;
    }

    String[] uniquewords = new String[count];
    int x = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < frequency.length; i++) {
        if (frequency[i] == 1) uniquewords[x++] = words[i];
    }
```

And your frequency check is not wrong as I originally stated. Just counting same words multiple times.

Comment: how can i do that mr.tonank?

Answer (score 0):

I made some adjustments to your code where I skipped the frequency count and also made sure the inner loop only compares "forward" from the current position in the outer loop. At the end I create a result array of the same size of the number of unique words, maybe this is not necessary and then you can skip that and have a print loop that loops over `uniquewords` using `counter` as the upper limit.

```
String[] words = new String[] {"hello", "hello", "i", "i", "am", "norman"};
    String[] uniquewords = new String[words.length]; 
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
        boolean isUnique = true;
        for (int j = (i + 1); j < words.length; j++){
            if (words[j].equals(words[i])){
                isUnique = false;
                i++;
                break;                    
            }
        }

        if (isUnique) {
            uniquewords[counter] = words[i];
            counter++;                
        }
    }

    String[] result = new String[counter];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = uniquewords[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

The last 2 loops can be replaced with a single loop if printing is the end goal

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
   System.out.println(uniquewords[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a first attempt, probably you are expected to write something like building a new array of unique words, re-allocating and copying every time when a new one is found:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"hello", "hello", "i", "i", "am", "norman"};
String[] uniquewords = new String[0];
for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    String word = words[i];
    boolean unique = true;
    for(int j = 0; j < uniquewords.length; j++) {
        if( word.equals(uniquewords[j]) ) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( unique ) {
        String more[] = new String[uniquewords.length + 1];
        for(int j = 0; j < uniquewords.length; j++) {
            more[j] = uniquewords[j];
        }
        more[more.length - 1] = word;
        uniquewords = more;
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < uniquewords.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(uniquewords[i]);
}
```

Test: https://ideone.com/gyH6fk

Then you can go for compacting the unique words into the beginning of the single array using two indices for tracking read and write position (`from` and `to` in the code):

```
String[] words = new String[] {"hello", "hello", "i", "i", "am", "norman"};
int from=0,to=0;
while(from < words.length) {
    String word = words[from];
    boolean unique = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < to; i++) {
        if( word.equals(words[i]) ) {
            unique = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if( unique ) {
        words[to] = word;
        to++;
    }
    from++;
}
for(int i = 0; i < to; i++) {
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}

//String[] uniquewords = new String[to];
//for(int i = 0; i < to; i++) {
//  uniquewords[i] = words[i];
//}
```

(The commented part creates a reduced-size array, if you need it.)
Test: https://ideone.com/5jVYnJ